# ViewFlipper with just one view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ViewFlipper that contains a LinearLayout which contains some TextViews.

When I go to the previous or next item (TextViews get updated with other values), I want the ViewFlipper to get a full animation. For example fade_in, fade_out.

For example:

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="435dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Flipper Content 1" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

When I click on next TextView01, I want to change its value to Flipper Content 2 with a full animation. For example, Flipper Content 1 gets out to the left then Flipper Content 2 comes in from the right.

Comment: you have asked viewFlipper with just 1 view..and you want  to go previous or next..how can it possible?

Comment: may be I was not clear, but in each time (previous, next) I change the TextView values dynamically.

Comment: it can be possible using viewFlipper but you should edit and make it clear.It depends on your requirement.

Comment: sure.Explain your requirements properly.

Comment: -late reply but you want left-to-right and right-to-left animation..am i right?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question properly. In the part where you create your screen you should acquire your ViewFlipper object and set InAnimation and OutAnimation

```
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper01 = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);
    viewFlipper01.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_in));
    viewFlipper01.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_out));
```

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.